# When does a "universal" quot scheme exist?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, coherent-sheaves, coarse-moduli-spaces

Suppose $M$ is a moduli space of semistable sheaves on a projective variety $X$. Let $v$ be some the discrete invariants. I would like to form a space $\mathcal Q(v) \rightarrow M$, where the fiber over a point $[E]$ of $M$ is the Quot scheme $Quot_X(E,v)$ of quotients of $E$ with invariants $v$.

If there is a universal family $\mathcal E$ on $M \times X$, then I believe $Quot_{M \times X}(\mathcal E, p_2^*v)$ should do the job.

**Question**
If $M$ doesn't have a universal family, is there some weaker condition that will still guarantee the existence of $\mathcal Q(v)$?

For my application, I am specifically interested in $\mathbb P^2$, so if the answer is easier there, that is of interest.

Comment: If the obstruction to a universal family is automorphism groups of points, you need to show that the pairs of $E$ and a quotient of $E$ with invariants $v$ have no automorphisms as a pair of sheaves with a map between them (other than scaling). It seems hard to find a nice sufficient condition in general for this but presumably you can often prove it in a particular case.

Comment: Generally speaking, points of $M$ parametrize S-equivalence classes of sheaves. If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are S-equivalent, there does not seem to be any reason for an isomorphism $Quot(E_1)\simeq Quot(E_2)$. So in this case, your $Q$ probably does not exist. On the other hand, if you restrict to stable locus (where no S-equivalence happens) the universal family exists locally in etale topology on $M$, so $Q(v)$ exists as an algebraic space. Whether it happens to be a scheme is another question.

Comment: For my application, I am happy to restrict to the stable locus.